# Difference between mysql and phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

What is difference between **MYSQL** and **PHPmyadmin**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL is a RDBMS (Relational DataBase Management System), PhpMyAdmin is a web application wich let you manage (with a visual interface) MySQL Databases.

Answer (score 5):

MYSQL is the most popular database server and PHPmyadmin is a web-based administrating tool for MYSQL. PHPMyadmin helps you to view the databases and tables and their data in a neat form and makes your life easy :) Actually, a little google would have helped you though

Answer (score 0):

They are not really comparable items.

MySQL is a Database and PHPmyAdmin is an Administration UI (for mySQL).